# Using storyboard seems to disable touch events?

Tags: coronasdk

Im a beginner to the Corona SDK.
I have 2 scenes A & B.

In scene A i have a button with a OnRelease event.
This button is created and added to the group in the scene Create event.
Clicking the button takes me to scene B ( storyboard.gotoScene("B") ).

In scene B i have a touch event on an box (crate image).
The touch listener is added in the scene Started event, and removed in the scene Exited event.
Clicking on the crate takes me back to A ( storyboard.gotoScene("A") ).

So here's the real annoying issue:
After going back to A, all events in this scene are now disabled.
i.e. I can no longer click on the button any more (no event).

Will provide code snippet if I am missing information above.
Thank you.

*** Update ***

After taking about a break from this, i went back today and started debugging this again. I found the issue fairly quickly. The problem had something to do with my touched event handler (which causes a transition from scene B to A).

snippet below that caused the issue:

```
function testTouched( event )

-- process cue-touched event...
--local t = event.target -- commenting this was the fix.
local phase = event.phase

if "began" == phase then

        print("     -> back to menu")
        --display.getCurrentStage():setFocus( t ) -- commenting this was the fix.
        --t.isFocus = true -- commenting this was the fix.
        storyboard.gotoScene( "menu", "flipFadeOutIn", 500 )

end

-- Stop further propagation of touch event
return true
```

Comment: yep, you should provide code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see [here](http://blog.anscamobile.com/2011/11/introducing-the-storyboard-api/),

> enterScene
>
> Dispatched when storyboard.gotoScene() is called, immediately after
>   the transition has completed. So if you specified a transition effect,
>   this event is dispatched as soon as the effect has ended. Adding
>   listeners, or app/game-specific logic should be placed in the listener
>   function for this event.
>
> exitScene
>
> When storyboard.gotoScene() is called, an “exitScene” event will be
>   dispatched to the currently shown scene before the transition occurs.
>   Cleanup duties, such as removing event listeners, stopping timers,
>   etc. should be placed in the listener function for this event.

Add event listeners in `enterScene()` event rather than `createScene()` and remove them at `exitScene()`?

**Edit**: I think you would need to `display.getCurrentStage():setFocus(nil)` in `exitScene()`.